# IBM Domino Mail Routing

Tags: ibm-domino

I have 2 Domino Servers as follows:

- ServerA: On LAN.  Runs SMTP & router, accepts inbound and outbound email.
- ServerB: External web server.  Runs router task only.
- Configuration document for Server A has:

  - SMTP used when sending messages outside of the local internet domain: Enabled
  - SMTP allowed within the local internet domain: All messages
  - Servers within the local Notes domain are reachable via SMTP over TCPIP: Always
- Configuration document for Server B has:

  - SMTP used when sending messages outside of the local internet domain: Disabled
  - SMTP allowed within the local internet domain: Disabled
  - Servers within the local Notes domain are reachable via SMTP over TCPIP: Only if in same Notes Named Network (because Always is the only other option)

Connection document is setup between both servers.  Port 1352 is open in both directions and replication occurs regularly.

As both servers are on the same Notes Named Network (NNN), my understanding was Notes would route mail natively from ServerB to ServerA as it knows ServerA is the mail sender.

The failure message on ServerB is:

```
'No route found to domain external-domain.com from server ServerB.  Check Server, Connection and Domain documents in the Domino Directory.'
```

- I am able to initiate a pull and push from ServerA to ServerB, and from ServerB to ServerA.  This was my proof that 1352 is open in both directions.
- I don't want ServerB to be able to route external mail and is blocked by firewall.  I want ServerA to send all mail.
- My understanding was if they are on the same NNN then no specific connection documents would be needed, and in fact are ignored.

Any suggestions for what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have a global domain document and an SMTP- Connection document from ServerA to the internet?

Comment: Hey Torsten - I setup a Foreign SMTP domain document, with Internet Domain as *.*, domain name set to be fictitious domain (smtp_email in my example), with a connection document from ServerA to a fictitious server (All_email in my example), with a destination domain of 'smtp_email - matching the setting in my foreign SMTP domain document, and the routing task set to be SMTP Mail Routing on the replication / routing tab - ServerB still tries to route the email.  I did restart router tasks on both servers, and the SMTP task on ServerA.